# glDrawArrays crash with GLES2

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

```
GLuint vBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
int totalSize = sizeof(tempVertexList);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, totalSize, tempVertexList, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);
```

This code crashes when it comes to glDrawArrays, any obvious reason I'm missing?
vertexCount is 4 and tempVertexList is filled with 4 Vertex structs defined as

```
typedef struct
{
    float Position[3];
    float Colour[4];
} Vertex;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float)*3));
```

needs to be called each time GL_ARRAY_BUFFER is changed, didn't know just found out :)